# What is time and space complexity for concating sorted array by using while loop?

Tags: javascript, arrays, algorithm

eg. here are two arrays

> a = [1, 3]
>   b = [2, 4, 5]

I used while loop to sort it

```js
var a=[1,3,6,7], b = [2, 4, 5];
var result = [];
var aPointer = 0;
var bPointer = 0;
while (aPointer < a.length || bPointer < b.length) {
  if (bPointer == b.length ) {
    result.push(... a.slice(aPointer));
    break;
  }

  if (aPointer == a.length ) {
    result.push(... b.slice(aPointer));
    break;
  }
  
  if (a[aPointer] < b[bPointer]) {
    result.push(a[aPointer]);
    aPointer++;
  } else {
    result.push(b[bPointer]);
    bPointer++;
  }
}
console.log(result);
```

I think the time complexity should be O(n + m) = O(n), space complexity is O(m + n + m + n) = O(2(m+n)) = O(2n). Is there better way to concat sorted array?

Comment: Don't know about complexity, but the code is not correct (try `a=[1,3,6,7]`

Comment: merge two sorted array will be similar to merge sort merging part.  So in worst case it would be O(n) where n size of bigger array. But I am not sure about your logic.

Comment: @cauchy, think about it: it cannot be better than *O(n+m)* as the result array must receive that many values. Putting each of the values there already requires *n+m* operations.

Comment: @trincot Yes I agree. What I meant was more of saying it would be in linear time. O(M+N) is simply max(O(M), O(N))

Comment: @georg, thanks, I have add the corner case for this program now

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The code is not completely correct. When all elements from `b` have been added to the result, and `a` still has values, then the `else` block will be executed, resulting in an endless loop of adding `undefined` to the result array.

Corrected code with different `while` condition and final concatenation of the remaining "rest" from one of the two input arrays:

```js
var a = [1, 3, 6, 7], b = [2, 4, 5];
var result = [];
var aPointer = 0;
var bPointer = 0;
while (aPointer < a.length && bPointer < b.length) {
  if (a[aPointer] < b[bPointer]) {
    result.push(a[aPointer]);
    aPointer++;
  } else {
    result.push(b[bPointer]);
    bPointer++;
  }
}
result = result.concat(a.slice(aPointer), b.slice(bPointer))
console.log(result);
```

The time complexity is *O(n+m)*, as each iteration of the loop pushes one value to the result, and the result will in the end have *n + m* values. The final `concat` and `slice` is just a short way to do the same for the remainder of one of the two input arrays. So the time complexity is not influenced by it.

The space complexity is usually expressed only in the extra space used, so not including the space used by the input. So apart from some constant space used by atomic variables (such as `aPointer`), there is the `result` array, which takes *O(n+m)* space.